# VSTS No Able To Report NUnit Category Attribute

Tags: nunit, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, vstest

Does anyone know how to report NUnit Category Attribute when tests are run through Visual Studio Team Services?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the categories to filter on when doing a testrun and you can name testruns.

There is nothing in place that will pick up the category when reporting to VSTS, so there is no way to filter on the results after the tests have executed.

If it's important to you, you can use multiple Test steps, filter each by the category you need and give the test run a specific Test run name. You can then filter the results by testrun.